# Text.Parser.Token.StyleのemptyIdentsの使い方について

Tags: haskell

`X(数字)`という形式の識別子をパースするパーサーを`parsers`ライブラリで書こうと思い、`Text.Parser.Token.Style.emptyIdents`を使って以下のような`IdentifierStyle`を定義しましたが、型エラーになってしまいます。

```
import Text.Trifecta
import Text.Parser.Token.Style

identStyle :: IdentifierStyle Parser
identStyle = emptyIdents {
  _styleStart = char 'X' :: Parser Char,
  _styleLetter = digit :: Parser Char
  }

-- パーサをこのように定義したい(例: "X3" -> Var 3)
ident = Var . (read . tail) <$> ident
```

現状はとりあえずnaiveに`ident = Var . read <$> (char 'X' >> many digit)`と定義していますが、何故上のコードで型エラーが出るのか知りたいです。

具体的な型エラーは以下のようになります。

```
No instance for (Text.Parser.Token.TokenParsing t0)
  arising from a use of    Text.Parser.Token.Style.emptyIdents   
The type variable    t0    is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance (Text.Parser.Token.TokenParsing m,
            Control.Monad.MonadPlus m) =>
           Text.Parser.Token.TokenParsing
             (transformers-0.3.0.0:Control.Monad.Trans.Identity.IdentityT m)
    -- Defined in    Text.Parser.Token   
  instance parsec-3.1.8:Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream
             s m ghc-prim:GHC.Types.Char =>
           Text.Parser.Token.TokenParsing
             (parsec-3.1.8:Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m)
    -- Defined in    Text.Parser.Token   
  instance attoparsec-0.12.1.3:Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Chunk
             t =>
           Text.Parser.Token.TokenParsing
             (attoparsec-0.12.1.3:Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Parser t)
    -- Defined in    Text.Parser.Token   
  ...plus 12 others
In the expression: Text.Parser.Token.Style.emptyIdents
In the expression:
  Text.Parser.Token.Style.emptyIdents
    {Text.Parser.Token._styleStart = Text.Parser.Char.char 'X' ::
                                       Text.Trifecta.Parser.Parser ghc-prim:GHC.Types.Char,
     Text.Parser.Token._styleLetter = Text.Parser.Char.digit ::
                                        Text.Trifecta.Parser.Parser ghc-prim:GHC.Types.Char}
In an equation for    identStyle   :
    identStyle
      = Text.Parser.Token.Style.emptyIdents
          {Text.Parser.Token._styleStart = Text.Parser.Char.char 'X' ::
                                             Text.Trifecta.Parser.Parser ghc-prim:GHC.Types.Char,
           Text.Parser.Token._styleLetter = Text.Parser.Char.digit ::
                                              Text.Trifecta.Parser.Parser ghc-prim:GHC.Types.Char}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskellのレコード更新構文は、更新の前後で型が変わらないことを要求しません。このため、更新後の型が決まっていても更新前の型が完全には決まらないことがあります。この例では、`emptyIndents`の型が`TokenParsing m => IdentifierStyle m`ですが、この`m`を決める手掛りがないため曖昧エラーが発生しています。

回避する方法はいくつかあります。

- 明示的に型注釈を与える。

  ```
  identStyle' :: IdentifierStyle Parser
  identStyle' = (emptyIdents :: IdentifierStyle Parser) {
    _styleStart = char 'X',
    _styleLetter = digit
    }
  ```
- 更新を二回に分けることで型の自由度をなくす。

  ```
  identStyle'' :: IdentifierStyle Parser
  identStyle'' = emptyIdents {
    _styleStart = char 'X'
    } {
    _styleLetter = digit
    }
  ```
- 用意されているレンズを使う。

  ```
  identStyle''' :: IdentifierStyle Parser
  identStyle''' = emptyIdents
    & styleStart .~ char 'X'
    & styleLetter .~ digit
  ```

Comment: なんと、レコード更新前後の値の型はunifyされないのですね。初めて知りました。ありがとうございます。レンズを使うのが正攻法っぽいですね。